# WinUI 3 on Windows 11 - Unable to find package Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools

Tags: visual-studio-2022, winui-3, windows-11

Setup:

OS Windows 11

Visual Studio 2022 community version 17.4.5

Workload installed: .Net Desktop development, Universal Windows Platform development.

Installation details:
.Net desktop development tools. Windows 11 SDK (10.0.22621.0)

I created a new project: Blank App, Packaged with Windows Application Packaging Project (WinUI 3 in Desktop)

Error list starts with

```
Unable to find package Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools. No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages, Package source  App3    C:\Users\Moshe\source\repos\App3\App3\App3.csproj
```

Same for all other packages.

Errors in the code  `The Type 'Window was not found'`

NuGet settings: Package Source `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\NuGetPackages\microsoft.windows.sdk.buildtools`
When opening this folder, it has a folder "10.0.22621.1" and in it under bin, are the packages reported missing.

Here is the .proj references

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>
    <TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
    <RootNamespace>App3</RootNamespace>
    <ApplicationManifest>app.manifest</ApplicationManifest>
    <Platforms>x86;x64</Platforms>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x86;win10-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
    <PublishProfile>win10-$(Platform).pubxml</PublishProfile>
    <UseWinUI>true</UseWinUI>
    <EnableMsixTooling>true</EnableMsixTooling>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Assets\SplashScreen.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\LockScreenLogo.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square150x150Logo.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square44x44Logo.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square44x44Logo.targetsize-24_altform-unplated.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\StoreLogo.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Wide310x150Logo.scale-200.png" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK" Version="1.2.221109.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools" Version="10.0.22621.755" />
    <Manifest Include="$(ApplicationManifest)" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <!-- 
    Defining the "Msix" ProjectCapability here allows the Single-project MSIX Packaging
    Tools extension to be activated for this project even if the Windows App SDK Nuget
    package has not yet been restored.
  -->
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(DisableMsixProjectCapabilityAddedByProject)'!='true' and '$(EnableMsixTooling)'=='true'">
    <ProjectCapability Include="Msix"/>
  </ItemGroup>

  <!-- 
    Defining the "HasPackageAndPublishMenuAddedByProject" property here allows the Solution 
    Explorer "Package and Publish" context menu entry to be enabled for this project even if 
    the Windows App SDK Nuget package has not yet been restored.
  -->
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(DisableHasPackageAndPublishMenuAddedByProject)'!='true' and '$(EnableMsixTooling)'=='true'">
    <HasPackageAndPublishMenu>true</HasPackageAndPublishMenu>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

What I tried so far:

Uninstall and reinstall Visual Studio.

Change SDK from Windows 11 to Windows 10 in Installer.

Use the other possible template under WinUI 3

Nothing helped.

Any pointers on how to resolve this

Thanks

Comment: Visual Studio 2012 ? are you sure?

Comment: My mistake - it is VS2022. I just edit the the post. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you mean Visual Studio **2022**, not 2012, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/set-up-your-development-environment?tabs=cs-vs-community%2Ccpp-vs-community%2Cvs-2022-17-1-a%2Cvs-2022-17-1-b#required-workloads-and-components) is where you can find the requirements. The list below is a short version of the link. Run the Visual Studio Installer and make sure you have these items selected.

- **Workloads** tab:

  - Select **.NET Desktop Development**.

    - Then, in the **Installation details** pane on the right, select **Windows App SDK C# Templates** for C# development.
    - If you also need C++, select **Windows App SDK C++ Templates**.
- **Individual components** tab:

  - Scroll all the way down to **SDKs, libraries, and frameworks** section and select **Windows 10 SDK (10.0.19041.0)**.

Comment: Yes, all the above is selected. I tried both Windows 10 SDK and Windows 11 SDK. 
Do I need to select 10.0.19401.0? no other version will work?
Thanks

Comment: That's what the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/set-up-your-development-environment?tabs=cs-vs-community%2Ccpp-vs-community%2Cvs-2022-17-1-a%2Cvs-2022-17-1-b#required-workloads-and-components:~:text=On%20the%20Individual%20components%20tab%20of%20the%20installation%20dialog%20box%2C%20in%20the%20SDKs%2C%20libraries%2C%20and%20frameworks%20section%2C%20make%20sure%20Windows%2010%20SDK%20(10.0.19041.0)%20is%20selected.) says.

Comment: I tried that and it did not make a difference. Same error. Something is very odd. Any other ideas? Thanks

Comment: Weird. I just happen to do these steps and had no problem. Can you try other templates? For example, "Blank App, Packaged (WinUI 3 in Desktop)" or the template from [Template Studio for WinUI](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TemplateStudio.TemplateStudioForWinUICs) extension.

Comment: Also, is your [NuGets Package source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/nuget/consume?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows#:~:text=when%20you%27re%20done.-,Install%20packages%20from%20your%20feed,-Now%20that%20you) "nuget.org"?

Comment: I will add a reply to myself in order to attach screenshots.

Comment: Actually, I don't see how to add an attachment to this thread. Do you know how? Is there a way in Stackoverflow to contact you directly?

Comment: Let's try this https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y08gsQF4-7TZsN29p9zrBWc9JufnBb8E/view?usp=sharing

Comment: <<Weird. I just happen to do these steps and had no problem. >> What is your setup? OS is Windows 11? What version? VS2022 - community? What version? Thank much

Comment: It's Win11 (22000.1574), VS 2022 Preview but I doubt that this is a version related issue. And sorry. I'm not allowed to click external links. You should be able to paste images from clipboard in your question.

Comment: I have used the latest version of VS 2022 and as you said it is probably not version related but still very wired. Thank you very much. I am giving it up for now as it is taking so much time. I might try using my other laptop with Windows 10.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Let me drop [this](https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK/issues/3161) just in case.

Comment: I didn’t have the time to try but this is very similar to my issue. I am out of the country with another laptop, But certainly going to try it and report back. Thank you very  much!