# Error opening XAML page in designer in a WinUI 3 (Windows App SDK) project using VS2022 Pro

Tags: visual-studio-2022, winui-3, windows-app-sdk

I have created a brand-new WinUI 3 / Windows App SDK project in VS2022 Pro using a Blank Project template. When I open MainWindow.xaml in design mode after successfully building the project I get the following error message:

[image]

There doesn't seem to be anything missing under Packages, nor are there any errors anywhere else. As far as I can tell, all the necessary SDKs have been installed:

[image]

I am running VS2022 as Administrator in Windows 11 Enterprise v10.0.22621.

Any idea what I am missing?

---

**UPDATE 1**

Updated the NuGet packages, rebuilt the project and am now seeing three errors:
[image]

---

**UPDATE 2**

Accepted auto-suggested fixes to add `xaml:` and `controls:` namespaces in front of XAML tag names and now the errors are gone:
[image]

However, so is the ability to open the page in VS designer even though it's enabled in **Tools > XAML Designer**.

Moreover, when I open the project in VS Blend it doesn't show the designer either.

What is missing from my project?

Comment: First thing is to upgrade the Windows App SDK packages to latest 1.3xx version (using Nuget update)

Comment: Done that and now I am seeing actual errors (see the update).

Comment: Strange. You can try to close VS and remove all bin and obj directories, or clear all nuget cache https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30933277/how-can-i-clear-the-nuget-package-cache-using-the-command-line, etc.

Answer (score 2):

WinUI 3 doesn't have a XAML designer and doesn't work with Blend. There's a ongoing discussion in the repo [here](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/5917). We'll might get one in the future but not anytime soon. It's mentioned in this [WinUI Community Call Feb 2023](https://youtu.be/xcgc5CLqUkM?t=3089).

Also, the XAML designer shouldn't be up in your project. A few months ago I had the same experience but I'm not sure why. I guess restarting Visual Studio or reloading the project fixed the issue that time and the XAML designer has not been up anymore.

BTW, this is how a default WinUI 3 MainWindow.xaml should look like:

```xml
<!-- Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation and Contributors. -->
<!-- Licensed under the MIT License. -->

<Window
    x:Class="TestWinUI3.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TestWinUI3"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Button x:Name="myButton" Click="myButton_Click">Click Me</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

If you keep having basic initial problems, make sure you have installed all the [workloads and components](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75480198/2411960), and create the project using **[Blank App, Packaged (WinUI 3 in Desktop)]** template.